# Simple Integration by Substitution requiring bizarre answer

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Before addressing my queries and attemps I shall be posting the full question below.

---

> Use the substitution $x=e^u$ to find $$\int (\ln x)^2dx$$

---

My answer boiled down to $\dfrac{2x^3}{3} + C$ however here is my attempt.

I first just substituted $x$ as requested just to see if I could get any hints from the resulting rewritten integral which ended up being $$\int \ln(e^u)^2dx$$
Now that things seems so simple I proceeded by simplifying this resulting integral (thinking I'm witty for having simplified it so much). $$\int 2u du$$

I simplified as follows and then evaluated accordingly and substituted back for $x$ to get the answer above.

---

As confident as I was with this, I turned over to the answer sheet only to find out $$x[(\ln x)^2 -2\ln x+2] +C$$

was the correct answer. So now here I am asking what on earth did I miss that must've been blatantly obvious to anyone else.

---

Comment: Thanks everyone for the quick replies. Makes sense now. Will rework and provide me new attempt shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $x=e^u$ implies $dx=e^u\,du$, so the integral becomes:

$$\int\ln(e^u)^2e^u\,du=\int u^2e^u\,du$$

Comment: Thanks Tim, got to the answer, simpler than I thought :-)

Comment: Yes, that's often the case when you come upon the right idea, the whole thing seems to fall into place. :)

Answer (score 2):

If $x=e^u$, then
$$
\int (\log x)^2 \, dx = \int u^2 e^u \, du.
$$

Answer (score 2):

We have:  $x=e^u \implies dx = e^u\,du$

This gives you the integral $$\int u^2e^u\,du$$

Integration by parts, twice, should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I got to the answer. Common mistake to rush through with the question instead of analyzing it properly :-)

Comment: You're welcome, Juxhin!